# Change the RSS Publication Date to use a value from a custom field

Tags: custom-field, rss

I have a site that wants to order its RSS output by a date value in a custom field.  I'd rather not create a new feed to do it -- how do I override the default feed date value?

Comment: [Here's an idea](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186118/make-rss-think-posts-are-new/186121#186121) how to use drag/drop if you have a *newsletter-feed* in mind. Do all posts have these custom fields? What's stored in there (format)? What did you try so far?

Comment: That's a good approach -- I'll give it a shot.  Thanks!